# I want to install Origin

Tags: wine, games

I am a complete and utter noob at using ubuntu and linux in general (I literally just put it on my second harddrive yesterday). I would like to get OriginEA onto my computer so that I can play games. I already have steam because there was an app in the software center. But EA doesn't have a compatible version. I already have wine, and when I downloaded the installation file, I right clicked it and hit run with wine. I had already installed it wrong so I reinstalled it. Now when I click on origin both on the taskbar and desktop, nothing. It flashes like it wants to load. I need to know everything I have to do to fix this! (also any info that would help me in the future with installing incompatible software would be great!)

Comment: See http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175 <- Origin apparently works, but not necessarily well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Ubuntu - and other Linux Distributions - look for the application 'PlayOnLinux', based on wine. It exists as (Ubuntu-/Debian-)package, is (cost-)free and guides you when installing (all kind of) MS-Windows-application; and does prefix-management to separate applications.

For an even more comfortable handling have a look at 'Crossover' from CodeWeavers; it's commercial, if only at moderate costs, though.

Both applications can/will help you to install Origin - amongst others.